# Can a person perform 'for' a domain or only 'in' a domain?

Tags: word-choice, phrases

Here's the original sentence:

> The person showed competence and mastery over the achievement domain for which she performed.

Other issues aside, the phrase "the achievement domain *for* which she performed" troubles me. I want to change it to "the achievement domain *in* which she performed."

Yes, no, or ixnay-moxnay; and why?

=== Update ===
The context is an intercollegiate sport performed in (for example) NCAA Division I; and the sport could be anything: basketball, volleyball, swimming, or some other sport.

Comment: Was the domain her audience?  Otherwise I'm not understanding how a domain can be performed for?  I'm not sure you're using "domain" correctly.  What, specifically did the person show competence and mastery of?

Comment: More context is needed here. The original sentence sounds odd to me, but I don't think your question can be answered without more information. "Achievement domain" sounds like jargon and doesn't give me any useful hits as a phrase.

Comment: Please see the === Update === in the orginal post.

Comment: I agree that "in" and not "for" is correct. In the case of choosing a correct preposition, I'm not sure that there is much of a reason to explain the correlation any more than there is a reason to explain why nouns describing non-gendered objects are masculine or feminine in languages like French. It is just a convention about which word is correct or not.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the meaning of "achievement domain", even with your update. And how is it different from simply the word "sport"? And why wouldn't you be concerned with the use of the word "over", as well? I may have mastery over my kingdom, but I don't think I would have mastery over a sport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask about "The person showed competence and mastery over the achievement domain for which she performed."

The words "achievement domain" are wrong here.  The statement is attempting to say that at the level at which she was performing, she showed skill and mastery.  At least that seems to be what the sentence is trying to say.

Thus:  *She showed competence and mastery of the sport at the level at which she was performing.*

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand the term "achievement domains" correctly, the three major domains are Work, Education, and Sports? The person being discussed was performing in the Sports Achievement Domain? And the subject displayed "competence and mastery" **in/over** the domain **for** which she was performing?

So the subject displayed a high ability level over the domain for which she was performing...

**for**

Answer (score 0):

Does that example come from real life or was it a school-room construct, please? If it’s really an intercollegiate sport which could be anything, it looks worryingly like an artificial construct.

Either way, it needs re-writing to produce many useful conclusions.

Is it fair to say ‘The person showed competence and mastery over…’ makes no useful contribution and the only wording actually to be considered is ‘the achievement domain for which she performed’?

As Kristina said, whatever an ‘achievement domain’ is, ‘for which she performed’ will normally describe the audience… which creates its own problems. If she’s a shot-putter, javelin-thrower, hurdler or all-round athlete, does she perform for one of those specific audiences, or for the arena in general?

As Katherine said, whatever ‘achievement domain’ means to you, it doesn’t seem to have a generally accepted meaning.
Whether or not there’s an exact match between any group of ‘performers’ and any given segment of the audience, if she’s an athlete she could perform either ’in’ the ‘achievement domain’ of athletics or ‘to’ an audience interested in that same ‘achievement domain.’

Comment: The example was a phrase in a PhD-level dissertation about sports.